# How to play video without sound using UIWebView

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview

I'm working on secure browser and for that reason I want to play all videos in a `UIWebView` with muted sound by default. How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, without native coding, it is not possible to mute/unmute purely through js in UIWebview.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemBecameCurrentNotif:)
                                             name:@"AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification"
                                           object:nil];


- (void)playerItemBecameCurrentNotif:(NSNotification*)notification {
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = notif.object;
    AVPlayer *player = [playerItem valueForKey:@"player"];
    [player setVolume:0.0];
}
```